# Parallel.For and web scraping issues

Tags: c#, web-scraping, duplicates, parallel.for

I am trying to make a multi threaded web scraper.For this I am using Parallel.For.Here is my code:

```
string source = "http://www.lolsummoners.com/ladders/eune/";
        string regex_Search = "leagues/.*>(.*)</a></td>";
        List<string> user_List = new List<string>();
        int page_Begin = 1;
        int page_End = 10;

        ParallelOptions p_Option = new ParallelOptions();
        p_Option.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3;
        Parallel.For(page_Begin, page_End, p_Option, index =>
            {
                try
                {
                    WebClient web = new WebClient();
                    web.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    String html = web.DownloadString(source + page_Begin);
                    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(html, @regex_Search);
                    foreach(Match match_Find in matches)
                    {
                        string user = match_Find.Groups[1].Value.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
                        user_List.Add(user);
                        Console.WriteLine(user);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                page_Begin++;
            });
        Console.ReadKey();
```

My problem is that if I use more than one thread,I get duplicates.Is there a way to fix this?I don't need the loop to get the same names from the same webpage,that's why I increment the page_Begin variable at the end.This is what I am talking about:
[image: Duplication issue]

Comment: You have a bigger problem - you're adding items to a List<T> instance from multiple concurrent threads. Your code is not suitable for concurrency for many reasons, List<T> and the duplications you see are just two of them. Have you considered DataFlow?

Comment: You should be using the `index` passed in rather than `page_Begin`

Comment: And how do I use that index? Sorry I am kinda new to C# and threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing duplicates because you're not using the *index* for the *current* parallel pass. Instead you're using `page_Begin` defined earlier.  So during two passes at least with two threads, both will start downloading at `1`!  With the increment, subsequent passes will download duplicates.

Change this line:

```
String html = web.DownloadString(source + page_Begin);
```

...to

```
String html = web.DownloadString(source + index );
```

### Concurrency woes

`List<>` isn't thread-safe so you may want to use a nice thread-safe collection from TPL such as `ConcurrentBag<>`.

MSDN:

> Bags are useful for storing objects when ordering doesn't matter, and unlike sets, bags support duplicates. ConcurrentBag is a thread-safe bag implementation, optimized for scenarios where the same thread will be both producing and consuming data stored in the bag.

The collections defined in `System.Collections.Concurrent` are all quite efficient and are much faster than the usual collections that are usually  written with `lock(object)`.

Change this:

```
List<string> user_List = new List<string>();
```

...to:

```
ConcurrentBag<string> user_List = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
```

Now you can add to the bag from any thread.

Later when you're done with threading, you can convert it to an array with `.ToArray()`.

Comment: @Cata Haha think nothing of it. It happens to us all. Sometimes it's just nice to talk it out :)

Comment: @Cata, you still need to synchronize the access to your `user_list` otherwise you may see unexpected behaviour. You can use a `ConcurrentQueue` or use a `lock`

Comment: @NimaAra And how do I synchronize the access?

Comment: @NimaAra Shay already mentioned that above, I'm only addressing the OP's immediate concern

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Really helpful :)

Comment: @Cata, remember if you use `ConcurrentBag` there is no guarantee to retrieve the items in the order at which they were inserted but then again in your case the order at which items are added to the `user_list` are not guaranteed due to the usage of `Parallel.For` but it is worth noting the difference between a `ConcurrentBag` and a `ConcurrentQueue` or simply locking the `user_list`

Comment: @NimaAra Good point!  That'll teach me to write an answer with a head cold :P  Time to lie down

Comment: Ok thanks. I have another question now.What if I want to increment the index by a different value than 1 ? Is that possible? Let's say I want the program instead of going through http://site/page=1 , http://site/page=2, and so on, I want it to go through http://site/page=1 ,http://site/page=11, http://site/page=21, and so on.

Comment: @Cata For that you might want to check out .NET's TPL DataFlow API. There you can pump in any source data your want, whether it is indexes; strings; URLs; objects; or puppies